# How do I get my Bluetooth speaker to connect with my laptop?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker, blueman

When I try to connect my Bluetooth speaker to my new Asus TP500LB, Blueman-Applet gives the option to use a "random passkey" or not to connect, but no option to enter the passkey that my speaker gives me. (The passkey is the default for this type of device: 0000) ***WTF!!!??***
How am I supposed to connect to any device with a passkey? This should be obvious. It looks like someone is trying to make things ***"easy"*** by reducing the functions available to the users. That's a bad idea every time. I am a VERY tech savvy person. I have been using computers since 1983. If I have difficulty with this, I guarantee others are having the same problem!

Bluetoothctl gives the following output when I try to connect:

```
[NEW] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 Monster Micro  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 Connected: yes  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 Paired: yes  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 Connected: no  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 Trusted: yes  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 RSSI: -73  
[bluetooth]#
```

attempting to pair from the cli yields:

```
[NEW] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 Monster Micro  
[bluetooth]# pair 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8  
Attempting to pair with 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 Connected: yes  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 Paired: yes  
Pairing successful  
[CHG] Device 10:B7:F6:02:F1:B8 Connected: no  
[bluetooth]#
```

I installed Bluedevil and tried bluedevil-wizard. Here is the output:

```
:~$ bluedevil.wizard: Manager initialized  
bluedevil.wizard: Initialize Discover Page  
bluedevil.wizard: Starting scanning  
bluedevil.wizard: Stopping scanning  
bluedevil.wizard: PIN:  "0000"  
bluedevil.wizard: Device type:  "headset"  
bluedevil.wizard: Legacy:  false  
bluedevil.wizard: From DB:  false  
bluedevil.wizard: PIN:  "0000"  
bluedevil.wizard: Initialize Pairing Page  
bluedevil.wizard: Pairing finished:  
bluedevil.wizard:    error     :  false  
bluedevil.wizard:    errorText :  ""  
bluedevil.wizard: Initialize Connect Page  
BluezQt: PendingCall Error: "No such file or directory"  
bluedevil.wizard: Connect finished:  
bluedevil.wizard:    error     :  true  
bluedevil.wizard:    errorText :  "No such file or directory"  
bluedevil.wizard: Initialize Fail Page
```

I also tried to connect with hcitool. No luck there either.

Trying to connect through the "Bluetooth Devices" applet yields the following:

```
Connection Failed: DBusFailedError: No such file or directory
```

Not sure which file is not there... Anyone have any ideas?

Well, this one has me stumped! I have been searching forums and Google for the last three hours with no luck. I suspect that the answer lies in the output of Bluedevil-Wizard when it says "No such file or directory". Its simply a matter of figuring out which file...